# yii2 rbac authmanager getRoles() return empty

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I'm implementing rbac using yii2. But when i try to get the roles that i previously created i get an empty variable : `$authorRole = $auth->getRole('admin');`

The rule class, where i put the actual rule logic.

> yii/console/controller/UserGroupRule.php

```
namespace app\rbac;

use Yii;
use yii\rbac\Rule;

/**
 * Checks if user group matches
 */
class UserGroupRule extends Rule
{
    public $name = 'userGroup';

    public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            $group = Yii::$app->user->identity->group;
            if ($item->name === 'admin') {
                return $group == 1;
            } elseif ($item->name === 'author') {
                return $group == 1 || $group == 2;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now defining the roles..

```
yii/console/controller/RbacController.php
namespace console\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class RbacController extends Controller
{
    public function actionInit()
    {
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

        $rule = new \app\rbac\UserGroupRule;
        $auth->add($rule);

        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $admin->ruleName = $rule->name;
        $auth->add($admin);

    }
}
```

After this i was able to run ./yii rbac/init to generate the rule files:

- console/rbac/items.php
- console/rbac/rules.php

This is mostly identical to the documentation

> yii/commom/config/main.php

```
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\rbac\PhpManager',
    'defaultRoles' => ['admin', 'author'], // your define roles
],
```

But in

> frontend\models\SignupForm::signup()

I get an empty result when i try to get the admin role :

```
public function signup()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->save(false);

        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
        $authorRole = $auth->getRole('admin');
        $auth->assign($authorRole, $user->getId());

        return $user;
    }

    return null;
}
```

here is the value of $auth :

```
yii\rbac\PhpManager#1
(
    [itemFile] => '/advanced/frontend/rbac/items.php'
    [assignmentFile] => '/advanced/frontend/rbac/assignments.php'
    [ruleFile] => '/advanced/frontend/rbac/rules.php'
    [*:items] => []
    [*:children] => []
    [*:assignments] => []
    [*:rules] => []
    [defaultRoles] => [
        0 => 'admin'
        1 => 'author'
        2 => 'admin'
        3 => 'author'
    ]
    [yii\base\Component:_events] => []
    [yii\base\Component:_behaviors] => null
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you generate the rbac in "console/rbac/items.php and
console/rbac/rules.php" but your rbac PhpManager is looking this files in advanced/frontend

You could move this files or set the correct paths

```
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\rbac\PhpManager',
    'itemFile' => '@common/rbac/items.php',
    'assignmentFile' => '@common/rbac/assignments.php',
    'ruleFile' => '@common/rbac/rules.php',
    'defaultRoles' => ['admin', 'author'], // your define roles
],
```

The "@common" is yii2 alias all available aliases listed here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/

This should help, let me know if there will be still an issue